# Should I make a HotelList class?

Tags: object-oriented, class

This question has always bothered me I am finally ready to ask it out here.

I am creating a hotel reservation app, and I am in the phase of deciding what classes I will have. Among classes such as `User`, `Hotel`, and `Ticket`, I also think whether I should have a `HotelList` class as well, which would be responsible for holding a list of hotels and sending it to the frontend when the user searches for hotels for a city.

This question is not confined to this particular example only. I am always in doubt about how I should treat "lists". I use Python, and in popular libraries such as Django, such "list" classes exist. For example, the Django official tutorial uses a BlogList class that handles blog queries.

Is it a good idea to have an ObjectList class? If not, which of the classes should be responsible to handle the list of hotels?

Comment: Nobody can answer this question without more context. Why do you think a `HotelList` class _might_ be a good idea, or is your question really "I don't understand why the Django tutorial does this kind of thing"?

Comment: @PhilipKendall more like the second.

Comment: What is the purpose of the class?

Comment: The purpose of the HotelList class is to get the hotel data from the CSV file and return it as a Python list.

Comment: You just described a function, not a class. Functions *do* things.

Comment: A good rule of thumb: If you are unsure if you need a class, then you don't.

Comment: Functions do things, whereas classes bind together multiple things (data and functions) into one big group, which you can have more than one copy of.

Comment: If the alternative to a `HotelList` class would be using a normal `list`, then you can compromise by declaring the variable/function as `List[Hotel]`, which has much the same effect with much less effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The purpose of the HotelList class is to get the hotel data from the CSV file and return it as a Python list.

You are, essentially, describing a repository. One whose data source is a CSV file. So, the answer is *Sure, why not*?

Maybe the tutorial doesn't use the name `HotelsRepository` because of the audience. Introducing, implicitly, design patterns in *" how to start"* guides and tutorials can be misleading and can shift the focus of the reader (*" what the hell is a repository and what do they have to do with Hotels? "*)

Regarding the *repositoy pattern*, it might interest you

- [P of EAA - Repository Pattern - Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

> *A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers, acting like an in-memory domain object collection.*

So. Is it necessary or not?

These sorts of questions must be addressed to the right audience. You. And they should be backed by needs (look at your source code). In this specific case, I have found the quote above to be a good reason to do it.

Now, you have to reach (or not) the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of the HotelList class is to get the hotel data from the CSV file and return it as a Python list.

You described a function, not a class.

Functions *do* things. Classes merely bind together multiple functions and data items into a group, and allow you to create multiple copies of the group. (A group that can't be copied is usually called a module or a namespace.)

In your case it seems like you simply need a function `def load_hotel_list(filename):` which returns a list of `Hotel`s.

If your design had more complexity, such as accessing *and changing* hotels in some kind of SQL database, then a class might be in order. But your design isn't like that.